# Django: How to represent MoneyField in Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, decimal, currency

I am using https://github.com/django-money/django-money for my currency.
The problem is it doesnt show anything in the form.

Here is how I have defined in the model.py

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Product(models.Model):
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

And in the forms.py

```
class ProductEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2) <-- one way to solve is to remove this but it will look like this imgur.com/a/7uFLX3y (how can I remove the currency selection and display the right currency)

    class Meta:
       model = Product
       fields = ("price")
```

I am using Django 1.11 and postgreSQL 9.4

Should I use forms.MoneyField ? How can I solve this form so that the price is displayed ?

Comment: What do you have in the form's `class Meta`? For a `ModelForm` to work you have to explicitly link it to the corresponding model.

Comment: good point, if i remove this in forms it works -->price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

Comment: however it shows also selectable currency list

Comment: Just seen the edit, the `class Meta` needs to be *inside* the form class. See the example at the top of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7uFLX3y like this

Comment: can you try using a CharField in the form?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350476/39296) post may help