# Render django's Multiwidget & MutliValueField Textarea using Crispy Forms

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a `TextField` intended to store a large amount of text that can be logically split into 10 parts. I thought that it would make sense to create 10 separate `Textarea`s, each for one logical part. Thus, I subclassed `MultiWidget` and `MultiValueField` like so:

```
class MultiWidget(forms.widgets.MultiWidget):
    template_name = "custom_content_widget.html"
    attrs = {"class": "textarea form-control"}

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = [Textarea()] * 10
        super(MultiWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return value
        return ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]


class ContentField(MultiValueField):
    widget = MultiWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Define one message for all fields.
        error_messages = {
            'required': 'This field is required.',
        }
        # Or define a different message for each field.
        fields = [CharField()] * 10

        super(ContentField, self).__init__(
            error_messages=error_messages, fields=fields, require_all_fields=True, *args, **kwargs)

        # self.helper = FormHelper()
        # self.helper.layout = Layout(
        #
        # )

    def compress(self, data_list):
        return " ".join(data_list)
```

with the `custom_content_widget.html` being just

```
{% for subwidget in widget.subwidgets %}
    {% with widget=subwidget %}
        {% include widget.template_name %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Simple model and form in which I'd like to use this multiwidget

```
class Opinion(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()

class OpinionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = ContentField()

    class Meta:
        model = Opinion
        fields = ('__all__')
```

The problem is that when I use `content` in my form's HMTL as `{{ form.content | as_crispy_field }}` it renders pretty ugly
[image]
and I'd like all of the `Textarea`s to be rendered one under the other. The main issue here is that `textarea` is rendered as

```
<textarea name="content_0" cols="40" rows="10" class="textarea" required id="id_content_0">
</textarea>
```

while "normal" `TextField` is rendered as

```
<textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" class="textarea form-control" required id="id_content">
</textarea>
```

and I have no clue how could I force the class of the widget to be `textarea form-control` instead of `textarea`. Initially, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330965/rendering-separate-multiwidget-fields-using-django-crispy-forms) and also [this blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html) but all they do is just to properly group widgets into rows and columns. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was to pass attributes dict with `"class": "textarea form-control"` to the `MultiWidget` constructor as follows

```
class ContentField(MultiValueField):
    widget = MultiWidget({"class": "textarea form-control"})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Define one message for all fields.
        error_messages = {
            'required': 'This field is required.',
        }
        # Or define a different message for each field.
        fields = [CharField()] * 10

        super(ContentField, self).__init__(
            error_messages=error_messages, fields=fields, require_all_fields=True, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        return " ".join(data_list)
```